# Auto Power on circuit when Electricity returns

Tags: power

I have setup a homeserver.. But there is lot of power outage in my location so when the power comes back i need to pess the power switch manually.
Is there a circuit which will just short the the push button once every time power is given to the Circuit.

Comment: Check BIOS settings. Most motherboard BIOS already have a setting for this very same purpose.

Comment: Mine is actually an old laptop so it doesn't have it

Comment: If it’s a laptop, then it usually has a battery that should be able to get you through power outages (provided they’re not too long and you of course still have the battery).

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE!  Please provide more details of your laptop or power switch circuit; in particular, does one side of the switch/button connected to ground?

Answer (score 1):

Just as @AJN has correctly opined, take a closer look at the BIOS setup. The setting can be hiding in power management setup, chipset setup, SuperIO setup, or other places.

I've also seen machines where the setting was not available in the SETUP, or was available, but wasn't reliable (sometimes the machine wouldn't start). In such cases, it is possible to come up with auto-power-up circuitry. In the past, I have tested a trivial trick with a signal schottky diode - such as the BAT42/BAT43. It must be a Schottky, as you need its low forward voltage drop (as compared to plain silicon signal diodes). And it better be a "signal" diode = specced for low forward current, rather than some beefy rectifier (because schottkies generally have an ugly = non-zero reverse current). You need to connect the diode such that the power button live pin (having a pull-up to +3.3V StandBy) gets pulled down by some stronger power rail, while the PSU is off. The trick hinges on the fact that the power button input signal is active low - and as soon as the strong/actuated PSU rails start up, the "button gets released". I.e. you don't even need to try timing the pulse or some such.

Let me hint at the connection in ASCII art:

PWRBTN -----|>|------ +5V

I.e., the thin "cathode identification stripe" on the diode body goes to +5V.

You can probably use +12V or +3.3V for that same purpose. Obviously it wouldn't work with +5VSB :-) Speaking of an ATX PSU output braid, the Schottky cathode can go to a red, yellow or orange wire, but not to the purple wire. The power button signal is NOT present in the ATX PSU braid, it's a dedicated input on the motherboard, in the "front panel header".

---- EDIT ----

So if this is a laptop, you will need to inspect the wiring of the power button, and if it principally matches the standard "ATX power button" function, you need to find some suitable power rail on the motherboard and connect the Schottky accordingly. You'll probably be messing among SMD devices anyway, so you may as well be interested to use a Schottky in SMD package, such as the BAR42. If the power button input follows some non-standard logic polarity or voltage level, you may need to modify the trick accordingly (such as, invert the signal somehow - with a FET, or a 74HC1G14 or some such).

Answer (score 1):

As the comment said, most Mainbord-Bios have that option to restart as soon as power returns (can't remember seeing one without)

The next thing which comes to mind is, atx power supplys have a power good signal

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX

Guess a simple circuit with a transistor, an relay and a bunch of resistors will be able to emulate the keypress. If you want to be sure, add an reset-IC for some nice delay.

Comment: If the power good is active high, and strong enough to pull the power button's pull-up low, then possibly all you need is a wire jumper. But careful not to drive the power button input too high, if the power btn input is 3.3V-tolerant and the PowerOK signal is at +5V level. In this scenario, again you need a schottky. Or some logic gate that's +5V tolerant at the input while powered by +3.3VSB.

Comment: A logic gate that's +5V tolerant at the input while powered by +3.3VSB: such as 74LVC1G125 / 74LVC1G126 or some such. The LVC logic family has this property.

Comment: OP has "it's a laptop" buried in the comments.

Comment: solution will work anyway: sense power supplys voltage, reset IC for detection and delay, Relais->emulate button press... maybe he needs to add a ne555 or so to get a single pulse (you must release the button after 2-3 seconds I guess), think a ne555 could also be used as the reset IC, so its only one IC again